# Generalised speed measure balances between entropy of proposal density and average acceptance

Tags: bayesian, markov-process, convergence, entropy

This is in reference to page 3 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.01373

In the following line after equation (3): the author mentioned that the generalised speed measure (a measure of speed for which a proposal distribution converges to its stationary distribution) balances between high entropy of the proposal and the average acceptance probability for a Markov Chain at initial state $x$.

1. It is unclear to me what this *tradeoff* is. Can it not be the case that both the proposal and the average acceptance probability is high?
2. How does $\beta$ balances the ratio of the entropy and the average acceptance probability?